# Error 3971 SQL SERVER + Python/Flask "El servidor no pudo reanudar la transacción"

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, transacciones, gunicorn

Tengo una aplicación en flask que maneja datos de SQL server a través de una conexión por pyodbc, con el driver ODBC 17, la aplicación funciona bien cuando se ejecuta en local, realiza todas las transacciones y todas las consultas, llamados a SP de manera correcta. Pero cuando se ejecuta en producción (servidor cloud, ubuntu), la mayoría de las veces aparece el error "El servidor no pudo reanudar la transacción". No hay diferencias entre el código ejecutado en local y el de producción.
Agradecería ayuda si es que a alguien le ha pasado algo similar, les dejo como imagen el error que aparece al comprobar el estado del socket de la aplicación en el servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo se te detiene el servicio de bases de datos?

Comment: No, el servicio sigue arriba,  las transacciones en producción a veces fallan y a veces no,  pero la mayoría de las veces fallan y aparece el error mencionado